# Android NotificationManager not working until reboot

Tags: android, notificationmanager

At first, the NotificationManager works fine, and when the system receives a notification request, notificationmanager.notify responds immediately. But when the system has been working for several hours, notificationmanager.notify is not triggered even when a notification request is received. No settings were changed during this time and no errors or warnings were shown in the logs.

Currently we know that if we restart the Android device, the notification manager will work normally again. So I assume the notification program is working, but is this a known issue with the notification manager? Is there any way to fix the problem without restarting the device?